# Do contractors expect a tip and if so how much?

Tags: contractors

I’m having an electrician upgrade my subpanel. The cost will probably be $1500 for labor and materials.

Should I tip them? If so what is expected?

(Note: I live in the US)

Comment: This is an extremely subjective thing and very culture/region specific as well. Also may depend on whether the electrician is part of a big company or a one-man operation, whether they quoted specific hours and stuck to it or billed based on actual time needed, whether they went "above and beyond" in terms of quality, etc. (I'm still waiting for my electrician's bill for heavy-up, so I can't tell you what I would do until I see the bill an decide what to do!) Because it is subjective (in *many* ways) it will almost certainly be closed as "opinion based". But I think it is an interesting Q.

Comment: As a computer consultant (a.k.a. professional geek) working basically for myself (just me and my evil twin), I do not expect tips. But I have gotten some nice ones over the years, and I have one wonderful small customer who *always* tips.

Comment: This is a matter of regional convention and opinion. VTC. That said, no, but a kind gesture can reap rewards.

Comment: A nice online review might be nice (or a scathing one if they screw up).

Comment: Movers, cleaners, dog walkers, the masseuse and caterers get a tip. Nobody else who gets paid to come to your house gets one. Pretty much everyone in the house *under contract* except the one who made it. The dude who shows up in the 2024 extended cab pickup truck just to grab a check *does not* get a tip.

Comment: Tips in my field (residential renovations, California) are few and far between. Everybody gets great service without tipping. However, a modest tip is always appreciated.

Comment: If you want to tip, after all it's the giving season, bucket them the same as (major appliance) delivery men and slip them $10 or $20.

Answer (score 4):

This is far less a question about home improvement and more about cultural norms.

I've grown up in America (Ohio) and the only times I regularly see tipping are: waiters/waitresses, tip jars at food/beverage places, cleaning staff (hotels, AirBnBs, or personal home), valets, bellhops, bartenders, delivery drivers (food or groceries, not UPS/FedEx), and Uber/Lyft/taxi drivers, casino workers, barbers/hairdressers, fingernail tech, and massage staff. Notice that none of these jobs are particularly high paying and they are service workers almost exclusively.

I try to do nice things for contractors like making sure they know they are welcome to use the bathroom in my house and offer coffee/water. It would never occur to me to tip them for doing the work they agreed to. I might tip if they did something outside the scope of the agreed to work and did it without expecting compensation, but that is normally not the case.

Answer (score 2):

May depend where in the world you are. In my part of the US it would be unusual, though it might happen if they somehow went above and beyond what you expected and didn't charge extra for doing so.

Some will appreciate low-cost but thoughtful things during the work (*i.e.*, doughnuts and coffee, but that can backfire when you get the gluten-free caffeine-avoiding electrician. There may be only one of those, though)

Comment: Then there was the time I had a tree taken down. I paid plenty for that, so I really wasn't inclined to tip. But they had several workers and it was hard work, so when they were hanging around at the end (I think waiting for the boss to show up or a truck or something) I brought out cold water bottles and they *definitely* appreciated that.

Comment: A few years ago we had movers in the house. When I announced I was going out to buy lunch and asked what they liked on their burgers and what to drink, it was definitely appreciated.

Comment: It's easy to hand out money.   It takes a bit more effort and time to treat people well.  When I have workers around I always ask if they need anything.  Then mention they are welcome to bottled water and if they need to use the restroom in my house, I'm fine with that. Sometimes I've grilled burgers for them if they didn't have lunches. I think that goes further than just handing them a $20 bill.